# Dataflow Jobs failing after launching

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, terraform-provider-gcp

We are setting up dataflow jobs using terraform, while launching the jobs, running into the below errors:

> 2021-10-12T16:12:54.996ZFailed to read the result file :
> gs://staging-bucket/dataflow/staging/template_launches/2021-10-12_09_09_45-13333812258007291359/operation_result
> with error message: (ff526486692ce85f): Unable to open template file:
> gs://staging-bucket/dataflow/staging/template_launches/2021-10-12_09_09_45-13333812258007291359/operation_result..

We had tested the template and images in a test project it worked fine, now we have migrated to another new project, where its failing with the above logs. Logs says it failed to read `template_launches` dir but the dir was not created at all in the bucket.
The logs are very abstract to find the actual issue, i reckon no permission issues but unable to identify the actual issue.

[image]

Comment: Since you are working on another project - has your service account used for dataflow write access to the bucket?

Answer (score 1):

you can validate these options:

- In your lunch program, you can check if you invoke  the “.run()”
  method.
- You could try to replicate it again in another project. You can see a
  tutorial: [how to create the dataflow process](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-templates).
- In case the issue persists, you can [report this issue](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers?hl=id).

Comment: Hi Raul, this issue persists - are you aware of any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the service account, after adding the mentioned roles in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/configuring-flex-templates#understanding_flex_template_permissions), the issue resolved.